# Twitter does not remember authorization

Tags: twitter, oauth, twitter-oauth, scribe

I am using Scribe (OAuth1.0) as a mechanism so that users can use their Twitter account to authenticate to my GWT/GAE application.

According https://dev.twitter.com/docs/auth/implementing-sign-twitter, there are 3 possible scenarios:
a/ User is Signed in and approved. In this case, Twitter should redirect the user transparantly back to my application url,
b/ user is Signed in but not authorize, or
c/ user is Not signed in

When Twitter comes back to my application (the callback), I use the verifier parameter to read the user data from twitter, which I use to determine the user in my application.

All of this works fine except for the following:

Scenario a/ is not working for me. Eventhough the user has already authorized my application to read his user data, Twitter seems not to remember this, and asks again to authorize access. (scenario b/).

Comment: I may have a solution: I could use the callback parameters to build the access token and store this in a cookie. I think the access token is permanent. When afterwards, the user tries to sign-in using Twitter, the application will use the access token from the cookie.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There are two URLs twitter offers for applications requesting an OAuth token:
`/oauth/authenticate` and `/oauth/authorize`. When an application directs users to the **authorize** endpoint - Twitter will request the user to authorize the application EVERY time they log-in. The **authenticate** endpoint will request authorization once and then any subsequent log-ins to Twitter will seamlessly pass-through to the application callback. This is more traditionally known as "signing in with your Twitter account".

In Scribe, the default is **authorize** - to change this to **authenticate** you need 2 things:

1. Ensure the  *Allow this application to be used to Sign in with Twitter* setting is checked in your Twitter application settings page.
2. In your application - when you specify the Scribe API class to use - instead of using `org.scribe.builder.api.TwitterApi.class` change this to `org.scribe.builder.api.TwitterApi.Authenticate.class`

Now your application will direct users to sign-in to the `/oauth/authenticate` endpoint and, if they have authorized your application at least once, they will just get passed through.

**Edit:**
Additional documentation - https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1#102

Comment: thanks a lot. I just had to change authorize to authenticate otherwise I was going through the api docs on twitter since 2 days